# If condition for comparing integer and float does not working

Tags: javascript, integer

I am using one If condition in javascript ,

```
var iid = "c_poqty_"+itemid;
var calculatedQuantity = document.getElementById(iid).value;

if(! isNaN(actualQuantity)) {
    if(actualQuantity >= calculatedQuantity) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("You must enter the order qty same or greater than the calculated PO Qty");
        document.getElementById(iid).focus();
        return false;
    }
} else {
    alert("Please Enter valid number");
    document.getElementById(iid).focus();
    return false;
}
```

Here, `calculatedQuantity` is always in float and while `actualQuantity` can be integer, 
I have one testcase:

```
calculatedQuantity = 1.0
actualQuantity = 1
```

Appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I suspect they're both *strings*. Certainly `calculatedQty` is, as you've retrieved it from the `value` of an input field, and the `value` property's value is always a string. Use `parseInt` and/or `parseFloat` so you're comparing numbers rather than strings.

Consider:

```
console.log("1.0" > "1"); // "true"
console.log(1.0 > 1);     // "false"
```

Comment: Consider creating numbers with `Number(someValue)`.

Comment: @xyu: Only if you want odd results if the user types odd things. `parseInt` and `parseFloat` are usually better choices for parsing end-user input.

Comment: You can always check if `isNaN(number)`

Comment: @xyu: And if the user types `"010"`? Some older browsers will interpret that as 8 if you use `Number()` (mistakenly applying octal). Whereas `parseInt("010", 10)` and `parseFloat("010")` *always* return `10`. As there's no advantage to `Number` and potential downsides, I'm not seeing an argument in favor. But whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate ! but I have tested it, its working fine as string too! but the major problem I am facing it when user have input actualQty = 1 and calculatedQty = 1.0 ; otherwise if i have input actualQty is 1.5 or more than 1.0 then its working fine.

Comment: @AffanPathan: If you want a numeric comparison, you can't use the value from `.value` directly, you **must** convert it to a number first. Again, `"1.0" > "1"` is true. So is `"1.5" > "1"`, and so with that value you might think it was working correctly, when in fact you're doing a string comparison, not a numeric one.

Comment: Okay If I am going with parseInt() and parseFloat() , so need to use both or parseInt() for integer value and parseFloat() for float value?  again we have not predicated the use mind even he can input 1.0 or 1 . plz suggest

Comment: @AffanPathan: Use `parseInt(theValue, 10)` when you need an integer (it's not *really* an integer, of course, because JavaScript doesn't have integers, but any fractional part of the string is ignored). Use `parseFloat(theValue)` when you need a float (note that you supply a radix to `parseInt`, but not to `parseFloat`; `parseFloat` always uses base 10). Which you use where is your call. Note that `parseInt("1.9", 10)` is `1` (not `1.9`, and importantly, not `2` -- there's no rounding), whereas `parseFloat("1.9")` is `1.9`.